# What is the impact on existing code to migrate from WebSphere MQ V6 to V7?

Tags: migration, ibm-mq

What is the impact on existing code to migrate from WebSphere MQ V6 to V7?

Can we make simply the change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like all good questions, the answer here is "it depends."

First of all, don't go to v7.0, go to V7.1 at least, better yet to V7.5.

- Using client or bindings mode connections?  You can upgrade the QMgr without touching a client-based app in most cases.  Any version of WMQ client can talk to any version of WMQ server, however its best not to leave apps on an unsupported version of WMQ client.  Of course, the app running on the old client won't get the new function such as automatic reconnect or performance improvements, even though the QMgr is at V7.5.
- Using SSL?  The SSLPEER element order changed and the commands to manage certificates changed.  Good news, cert management is now performed with `runmq*km` commands living in the `{mq install}/bin` directory so you don't need to hunt down the GSKit directory and figure out whether to use `gsk6*`, `gsk7*` or `gsk8*` commands.
- If you go from 32 to 64 bit, you may need to recompile programs or exits.
- Correct settings for `PATH`, `CLASSPATH` and `LIBPATH` change across versions.

There's much more and it's well covered in the Infoceenter.  Each Infocenter has a section on migration.  Within that section, there's subsections by version and within those there are subsections by platform.  Pick the target version of WMQ (that's V7.5, right? Say yes!) and and drill down.  Start here:

- [Migration from V6.0 to V7.5](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r5/topic/com.ibm.mq.doc/mi67501_.htm)
- [Migration from V6.0 to V7.1](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r1/topic/com.ibm.mq.doc/mi67101_.htm)
- [Migration from V6.0 to V7.0](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.mq.csqzao.doc/mi24130_.htm)

Comment: Thanx, why I should not go to version 7.0 but rather 7.1 and better the version 7.5 ?

Comment: V7.1 introduced many new security features, including CHLAUTH records which provide native QMgr functionality that formerly required channel exits.  V7.5 integrated WMQ AMS and FTE components. Even though they are still licensed separately, the tighter integration further improves security as well as function and performance.  Any version of client can operate with any version of QMgr so you can migrate these each on their own schedule. Best case, use swing hardware for the new QMgr to get a V7.1 or V7.5 QMgr, then migrate apps onto it and decommission the old QMgr when complete.